# Issues creating Google Web Signin with PHP

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

I've been trying to follow the documentation on googles websites for the new identity web-signin, and although I've been successful in getting *something* to work (I really don't know how it's supposed to work even after reading the documentation, as most tutorials and examples are utilizing the old examples) I need some clarity on a few points.

Point 1) Do we still need access/refresh tokens? I dont receive those through the payload and I'm unsure of how to implement them.

Point 2) Is this even the right way to implement the google signin?

Here are my basic pages...

Index.php

```
    <!-- display the login prompt -->
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="<?php echo $google_oauth_client_id; ?>"
        data-context="signin"
        data-callback="googleLoginEndpoint"
        data-close_on_tap_outside="false">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="pill"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
     
     
    <!-- create a hidden form for submitting the data -->
    <form id="googleLoginForm" action="google-sign-in.php" method="post" style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_token" id="id_token">
    </form>
     
<?php endif; ?>


<script>
    // callback function that will be called when the user is successfully logged-in with Google
    function googleLoginEndpoint(googleUser) {
        // get user information from Google
        console.log(googleUser);
 
        // populate the form with the Google ID token
        var idTokenField = document.getElementById('id_token');
        idTokenField.value = googleUser.credential;
 
        // submit the form
        document.getElementById('googleLoginForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Google-sign-in.php

```
<?php
    // Enable error reporting for all this code
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // Use sessions
    session_start();

    // Include Google API client
    require_once "path/to/vendor/autoload.php";

    // Set Google client ID
    $google_oauth_client_id = "CLIENT_ID";

    // Create Google client object with client ID
    $client = new Google_Client([
        'client_id' => $google_oauth_client_id
    ]);

    // Verify the token sent from AJAX
    $id_token = $_POST["id_token"];

    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
    if ($payload && $payload['aud'] == $google_oauth_client_id) {
        // Get user information from Google
        $uid = $payload['sub'];
        echo $uid;
        
        // Prepare data for the API request
        $chkdata = [
            'uid' => $uid
        ];

        // Convert data to JSON
        $json_data = json_encode($chkdata);
        echo $json_data;
        // API URL for user existence check
        $api_check_url = 'API that checks if user is already in database';

        // Initialize cURL for user existence check
        $ch_check = curl_init($api_check_url);
        curl_setopt($ch_check, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch_check, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); // Use a custom request method
        curl_setopt($ch_check, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
        curl_setopt($ch_check, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data)
        ]);

        // Execute the user existence check request
        $check_response = curl_exec($ch_check);
        echo $check_response;

        // Check for errors in user existence check request
        if ($check_response === false) {
            echo 'Error in user existence check: ' . curl_error($ch_check);
            exit;
        }

        // Close cURL for user existence check
        curl_close($ch_check);

        // Decode the JSON response for user existence check
        $check_result = json_decode($check_response, true);
        if ($check_result === null) {
            echo 'Error decoding check response JSON: ' . json_last_error_msg();
            exit;
        }

        // Check if there was an error in user existence check response
        if (isset($check_result['error'])) {
            echo 'Error in user existence check: ' . $check_result['error'];
            exit;
        }
         
         
         // Get user information from Google
            $name = $payload["name"];
            $email = $payload["email"];
            $picture = $payload["picture"];
            $first_name = $payload["given_name"];
            $last_name = $payload["family_name"];
            $verified_email = $payload["email_verified"];

        // Check if user exists based on the API response
        if ($check_result[0]['uid'] === 'NULL') {
            // User does not exist, enter the data to the API

            // Save user variables to session tokens
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['picture'] = $picture;
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
            $_SESSION['verified_email'] = $verified_email;

            // Prepare data for the API request
            $data = [
                'email' => $email,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'full_name' => $name,
                'picture' => $picture,
                'verifiedemail' => $verified_email,
                'sso_provider' => 1,
                'uid' => $uid
            ];

            // Convert data to JSON
            $json_data = json_encode($data);

            // API URL for creating a new user
            $api_create_url = 'API that inserts new user into database';

            // Initialize cURL for creating a new user
            $ch_create = curl_init($api_create_url);
            curl_setopt($ch_create, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch_create, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch_create, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
            curl_setopt($ch_create, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data)
            ]);

            // Execute the user creation request
            $create_response = curl_exec($ch_create);

            // Check for errors in user creation request
            if ($create_response === false) {
                echo 'Error in user creation: ' . curl_error($ch_create);
                exit;
            }

            // Close cURL for user creation
            curl_close($ch_create);

            // Decode the JSON response for user creation
            $create_result = json_decode($create_response, true);
            if ($create_result === null) {
                echo 'Error decoding create response JSON: ' . json_last_error_msg();
                exit;
            }

            // Check if there was an error in user creation response
            if (isset($create_result['error'])) {
                echo 'Error in user creation: ' . $create_result['error'];
                exit;
            }

            // Retrieve the token from the response
            if (isset($create_result['uid'])) {
                // Save user token into session
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $create_result['uid'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['picture'] = $picture;
                $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
                $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
                $_SESSION['verified_email'] = $verified_email;

                // Redirect to profile.php
              header("Location: profile.php");
          //     echo 'new user', $_SESSION['uid'];
                exit;
            } else {
                // Handle the case where the token is not present
                echo 'Error: User token not found.';
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            // User already exists, retrieve the token from the response
            $existing_token = $check_result[0]['uid'];

            // Save user token into session
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $existing_token;

            // Save user variables to session tokens
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['picture'] = $picture;
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
            $_SESSION['verified_email'] = $verified_email;
            

            // Redirect to profile.php
          //  header("Location: profile.php");
            echo 'old user', $_SESSION['uid'];
            echo $payload;  
            
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        // Token is not verified or expired
        echo "Failed to login.";
    }
    

?>
```

I am unsure of whether this is the right way of implementing the new google login, and what happens when a user revokes accuse, I am confused on how to handle that scenario.